# Wordpress ACF query posts where datetime field is empty or older than 1 day

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a custom post type (`affiliate_products`) with a price field that I update daily via an API and a WP Cron job. Because I have so many affiliate products on my website, I divide them into batches of 5, with a cron that runs every minute.

For this, I am using an ACF DateTime field `last_update` that is updated with the current date and time when it is updated. But I am having trouble with my WP query;

I need to get 5 posts where the `last_update` field is empty (new products that have not been updated yet) OR where the last update was more than 1 day ago. (date < today)

But my query is not working. The first part of the meta query is working, but as soon as I add the second part of the meta_query, no results are returned anymore, even though there are still plenty of products with an empty last_update field. What could be wrong with my code?

I realize I don't have any products yet with a `last_update` date of > 1 day, but it should still be returning products with an empty `last_update` field, right?

```
$args_products = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 5,
        'post_type'         => 'affiliate_products',
        'meta_query'        => array(
            'relation'          => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'last_update',
                    'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'last_update',
                    'value'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'compare'   => '<',
                    'type'      => 'DATETIME'
                ),
            )
    );

    $the_product_query = new WP_Query( $args_products );

    if( $the_product_query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $the_product_query->have_posts() ) { 
            $the_product_query->the_post();
            // the update code goes here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Ymd` format. check here [date-picker](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/)

```
$args_products = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 5,
    'post_type'         => 'affiliate_products',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        'relation'          => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => 'last_update',
                'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'last_update',
                'value'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-1 day')),
                'compare'   => '<',
                'type'      => 'DATETIME'
            ),
        )
);

$the_product_query = new WP_Query( $args_products );

if( $the_product_query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $the_product_query->have_posts() ) { 
        $the_product_query->the_post();
        // the update code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: But I am using a DateTime field, won't I need the time information as well to make sure a product gets updated every day (every 24 hours)?

Comment: Did you check how it stored in the database?

Comment: According to ACF documentation (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-time-picker/) it is stored in the database as Y-m-d H:i:s.

Comment: you said the `last_update ` key exists but the value is empty?

Comment: The first part of the meta query selects the products where the `last_update` field is empty (so new products that haven't been automatically updated yet). This is working fine. I think the problem is with the second part of the meta query, with the DATETIME value. When I comment out the rest of the meta query and only leave this part, then the same 5 products get updated each run (every minute), even though they have been updated just a minute ago. So there is a problem with that part of the query, but I don't know what. I followed the ACF documentation..

Comment: the same 5 products get updated each run (every minute), even though they have been updated just a minute ago
=> It because the current time always greater than `last_update` so I think you need to update `last_update` by adding some extra time.

Comment: Aha, that's a good point. I did some searching and I needed to use something like, `strtotime('- 1day')`, I have edited it in my code and everything is now working perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Just update the 'type' to DATETIME, and then it's the working code which I'll accept as the answer!